# How to prevent browser from saving webpage in cache, or force to request new page each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can this be done by adding HTML code, to request the page from server instead of from cache, each time the page loads?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "user" - do you mean the browser's automated caching mechanism, or the user actively saving the page on their machine?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't access the server'? Aren't your page loaded from server?

Comment: m using the server of some other site

Answer (score 4):

The only working option is to never use the same URL twice which is done by adding a fake request parameter with random value.

Most client side AJAX frameworks do this.

Comment: how to send fake request code in js??

Comment: Append it to the URL with JavaScript. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667927/javascript-url-containing-random-number

Answer (score 1):

You can use these meta tags :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Add this in the `<head>` section of the page

[More info on meta tags here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta)

Comment: (Note this is not supported by all browsers. The server-side header is the only fully-reliable way.)

Comment: @bobince there is no HTML meta way of doing this ?

Comment: According to W3C Schools it is supported by all major browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: @Drahkar [please dont believe everything you read at W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: `http-equiv="content-type"` works on all browsers, but other headers don't necessarily. Many headers have to be processed before HTML parsing starts, which would preclude `meta` from affecting them. `content-type` is special-cased and yeah, it's a bit misleading and ugly in the way it repurposes what was originally intended to be a server-side processing directive. (That's why HTML5 encourages `<meta charset="utf-8">` instead... though I would stick with `http-equiv` for that for the moment due to better support in older browsers.)

Comment: (FWIW, the edited version with all three headers works better as this picks up WebKit, which Pragma alone does not.)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid caching you can append the timestamp as a parameter

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime() 
  //append it to an url when you make an ajax call or to a link

 var myLink = document.getElementByID('yourlink');
 myLink.href = myLink.href + '&nocache='+timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the head section, you can add the **no-cache** directive. When Cache-Control: no-cache is set, the browser will send the http request to the server and validate before releasing a cached copy.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

You use the **Expires** directive and set the time to a value that is before the request time, which will make the browser request the server for every subsequent request. The **max-age** directive is also similar to Expires and can be used for this.

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content=-10>
```

Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching