# caching issue with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, caching

I am getting data through $.ajax multiple times. However the data is not getting refreshed in every call. Rather I am getting the same data in every call to $.ajax. The code was working properly at my home.

However in below code if I substitute console.log("success "); with console.log("success "+data); and observe in chrome console, then the code works fine. I suspect its a caching issue, but can figure it out.

```
    function getDataJSON()
    {
        originalData="";
        new Date().toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
            data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
            success: function(data)         
            {
                console.log("success ");
                ...
                ...
```

Thanks

Comment: did u  tried cache=false in ajax setup ?

Answer (score 2):

you can set cache [Cache](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). by default it will set to cache=true. 
from DOCS

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

```
$.ajax({
url:'url',
cache:false,

.....
})
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried it earlier but it wasnt working. After your answer I tried again and this time its working. Guess I will wait for some more tests and will revert if the functionality works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ravi said cache priperty is you're frined.

You should realy spend more time on studying you're weapon of choice!
[Link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) => first hit on google if you search **jquery ajax**

There is another method of preventing caching. Just append some random number to url you are accessing.

For example:

```
        "www.url.com?" + new Date().getTime()
or
        "www.url.com?" + Math.random()
```

from [Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667927/javascript-url-containing-random-number)

Comment: You really missed my comment to @Ravi's answer. I did that and it didnt work. I dont know why. I thought it might be because the jQuery page tells that "cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests" and I didnt get it. BTW, I alsi tried new Date().getTime() and I dont know why, but it also didnt work.